# WPF DataGrid double click via commands + INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want a command in my ViewModel to be executed when DataGrid item is clicked. As a parameter I want to have corresponding row.

I've found one approach in internet but it using `DependencyProperty`

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/632ea875-a5b8-4d47-85b3-b30f28e0b827

I don't use `DependencyProperty` in my project, instead i'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. How to implement "double click in datagrid" commaind without using `DependencyProperty`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
...
<DataGrid SelectedItem={Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: will it pass which row is clicked somehow?

Comment: if you add a MySelectedItem to your ViewModel and use TwoWay binding, your viewmodel will be aware of the selected item. so kinda but it's better IMO

Comment: hm...... can I use this with C# project? because VS suggest me to reference some Visual Basic files

Comment: you need to add the following reference: System.Windows.Interactivity. Yes this works with C#.

Comment: thanks, it works. may you also help me to do this? "if you add a MySelectedItem to your ViewModel and use TwoWay binding, your viewmodel will be aware of the selected item. so kinda but it's better IMO"

Comment: i will try to do this myself using this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf ...

Comment: I keep adding the dll and posting that exact code into my XAML but It still can't find Interaction.Triggers

Answer (score 3):

I usually use an [AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/). It's 3 class files which can be added to your project, and lets you attach commands to just about any event.

Here's an example of how it can be used:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="MouseDoubleClick" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Action" Value="{Binding MyDoubleClickCommand}" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) provides EventToCommand behavior, this should be able to achieve the desired behavior (you can always roll your own if you don't want to use the framework).

Comment: i'm not sure I would like to add framework. my application is pretty small and so far it's fine without framework. how to do what I want to do without framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this code-behind](http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com/2011/01/wpf-datagrid-row-double-click.html) snippet to identify the row that is double clicked.

In the line with the comment *"//do something with the underlying data"* you can get the attached ViewModel from the Grid's or row's DataContext and Invoke your Command with the row as parameter.

Comment: it's against wpf pattern as well. I would like to use commands and binding