# wpf datagrid row Foreground in code behind

Tags: wpf, datagrid, foreground

I don't want to use MVVM and want to change the selected row Foreground on my datagrid in code behind (in SelectionChanged EventHandler function), but I can't find the solid way.

My row can be black, blue and red, but shows the color with a higher priority based on some condition. After selecting the current row I should remove, f.e. black color from my priority list.

I have some class:

```
public class TempClass{ public string cell1 { get; set; }; public string cell2 { get; set; };}
```

and

```
TempClass[] collection;
```

bound with my datagrid:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var rowStyle = new Style {TargetType = typeof (DataGridRow)};
rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
var rowTrigger = new Trigger {Property = DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty, Value = true};
rowTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
rowTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Orange));
rowStyle.Triggers.Add(rowTrigger);

var cellStyle = new Style {TargetType = typeof (DataGridCell)};
var cellTrigger = new Trigger {Property = DataGridCell.IsSelectedProperty, Value = true};
cellTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
cellTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Orange));
cellStyle.Triggers.Add(cellTrigger);

datagrid.RowStyle = rowStyle;
datagrid.CellStyle = cellStyle;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to change the **SELECTED** row Foreground on my datagrid in code behind. My row can be black, blue and red, but shows the color with a higher priority based on some condition. After selecting the current row I should remove, f.e. black color from my priority list.

Comment: I see, well, I updated the answer with sample on how you can write a trigger in .cs

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's fine with Styles and Setters, can you please add on your answer how to reach to the Selected "`DataGridRow`" in my dataGrid, because I have `TempClass[] collection;` and `datagrid.ItemsSource = collection;`. When I trying to get Selected `DataGridRow` like: 
`DataGridRow currentRow = datagrid.SelectedItem as DataGridRow` 
the currentRow is null;

Comment: ah, for this check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf

Comment: Thank you very much Denis Morozov, I didn't know it was so confused to get the selected row of DataGrid :(