# Method to find DataGrid Row is selected or not?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and WPF. Issue I have is on datagrid I am displaying datatable data. I need to update data based on selected row. I am able to achieve that.

However, when I do not select any row on datagrid it does select default row as '0' and I do not want that I want result as -1 or error because I have not selected any row there?

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if a row is selected with `dataGrid.SelectedIndex`; if the value is `>= 0`, you have a row selected.

To access the selected row:

```
if (dataGrid.SelectedIndex != -1) {
    YourDataType row = (YourDataType)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
    // process stuff
}
```

In the event that you allow multiple selections in your data grid, a very reasonable assumption, you can access the collection with the `dataGrid.SelectedItems` property.

A similar answer that shows example XAML too can be seen here: [Get selected row item in DataGrid WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear about what actually you wanted to do. Just set `yourdatagrid.SelectedIndex=-1;` in some sort of initialization part of your code.

Comment: Thank You sir! it worked. I was looking for undefault value and never thought of initialized that before..

Comment: A wise man once said "it's not the answer that counts, but the solution" ;)