# Grabbing second column value of Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hi I'm trying to grab the second column value on click and to display in a text box but im really new to C#.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)  
{  
   display.Text = Datagrid.SelectedItem.ToString();  
}
```

This displays all columns, but i only want second column, the second colummn header is Name.

```
var query = from loan in Loans  
        select new {Date = loan.StatusCommittedDate, Name = loan.PublicationName}  

DataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: How are you filling your DataGrid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected row item in DataGrid WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your datagrid is binded this may work

private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e) 
{

```
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

    int selectedIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;

    if (selectedIndex > -1)
    {

        DataGridColumn column = dataGrid.Columns[0];
        Label lblName = (Label)column.FindControl("ControloftheIDwithPublicationNameBinded");
        display.text = lblName.text;
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps