# How to get datagrid selected row value in textbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want datagrid selected value in textbox.

I tried this code

```
private void datagrid1_SelectionChange(object Sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
    var selectedrow = datagrid1.selectedItem as datarowview;
    var id = selectedrow["Tagid"];  // Here I get error that object reference is not set is an instance of an object 
    string s = conver.tostring(id);
    txttextbox1.text= s;
}
```

It works fine.

But when I refresh (or reload) `datagrid1` then selectionChange throws an error:

> Object reference is not instance of an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf

Comment: I already have look to this solution but not useful for me. coz I dont want to use viewmodel

Comment: How are you populating the datagrid ?

Comment: on button click datagried.Itemsource= dt.defaultview;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML

```
  <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   SelectionChanged="DataGrid_Details_SelectionChanged">
```

and in `.cs` file add

```
   private void DataGrid_Details_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var row_list = GetDataGridRows(MyGrid);
            foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list)
            {
                if (single_row.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    //Get your value over here
                }
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (null != row) yield return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank again for your valuable solution . And This work for me perfectly.