# WPF: add dynamic ToolTip to DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tooltip, datagridcell

I'm developing my first WPF application that queries a database and shows some records of some tables in `TabControl` if one or more fields of these records not satisfy certain condition.

I have a `DataTable` as data source and I use a `DataGrid` to show results (i.e. the wrong records). I'd like to use `ToolTip` on `DataGridCell` to indicate why a field is considered wrong. There's a way to iterate over the `DataGridRow` and the `DataGridCell` so that I can set dynamic `ToolTip`for every specific field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the DataGrid selected item to a SelectedRecord property in my view model (where the data source is coming from), see [Get selected row item in DataGrid WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf) as an example. The SelectedRecord property would then set the SelectedRecordToolTip property in accordance to the SelectedRecord value (i.e. using a dictionary with the error as the key and the tooltip as the value). Finally, you can then bind your tooltip to the SelectedRecordToolTip property.