# C# WPF: DataGrid, Delete selected row

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a DataGrid which I linked to a DataBase (Table). My question is how can I delete a selected row (using btn_click) from the DataGrid and also delete the same data from the DataBase (Table).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the currently selected item of a `DataGrid` using the `SelectedItem` property.

Your can then call the `Remove` method to remove the item from the `DataGrid`

```
var selectedItem = myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
if (selectedItem != null)
{
   myDataGrid.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
}
```

After the first line you need to extract the information (e.g. some Id) from the item in order to delete it in the database.
Usually you cast the `SelectedItem` to the object you used to bind to the grid.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf) response.