# How to Pass Cell Information from DataGrid in WPF KeyBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, key-bindings

I'm having a DataGrid to list the MobileInfo Collection. The DataGrid is Configured with `SelectionUnit="FullRow"`. If I Click the any Row then it selects the entire row with additionally it points the Cell with border where the Mouse was hit. The Border Selection moves while on Keyboard navigation For Example : `Left`, `Right`, `Up` and `Down`. Based on the Cell Selection I wish to Pass the Information about the Cell.

Refer the Image it has the Output Screen

[image: Cell Selected in OS Column]

In the above Screen Shot the Android is Selected, Based on Keyboard Navigation, the Cell selection gets changed.

My XAML Source Code:

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MobileList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CopyToClipBoardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Column 1-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileName}" Header="Name" />
        <!--Column 2-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileOS}" Header="OS" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

> Note: Don't Change the **SelectionUnit** in the DataGrid

Kindly provide your solution, how to pass the Cell Information based on Keyboard Navigation

The C# Source Code associated with the XAML DataGrid

```
public class GridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MobileInfo> MobileList { get; set; }

    public GridViewModel()
    {
        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileInfo>();
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo  { MobileName = "iPhone", MobileOS = "iOS" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo { MobileName = "Xperia", MobileOS = "Android" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo { MobileName = "Lumina", MobileOS = "Windows" });
    }

}

public class MobileInfo
{
    public string MobileName { get; set; }
    public string MobileOS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cell information"? The value in the cell? Display index of the corresponding column? The header of the column?

Comment: The easiest is to bind datagrid's [`SelectedItem`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3913580/1997232) and use it in your command processing code instead of trying to pass something via `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Can you post your `ICommand` code too?

Comment: @IlVic - Yes I'm using MVVM approach

Comment: @Grx70 - Either Value of the Cell or DataGrid.Cell - I extract the Value from DataGrid.Cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the command parameter to [`DataGrid.CurrentCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx) property. There are several ways to accomplish that, one of which is specifying relative source for the binding:

```
<KeyBinding Key="C"
            Modifiers="Control"
            Command="{Binding CopyToClipBoardCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentCell, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
```

Note that I removed the `DataContext.` part from the command binding path (`DataContext` is the default source for binding if source is not explicitly specified).

The command parameter will now be an object of type [`DataGridCellInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a **structure**, and not a class.

You can modify the command parameter binding path to extract more specific info.

Comment: How to get Value from DataGridCellInfo?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan I'm afraid there's no easy way to do that (let alone a pure _MVVM_ one). The reason is that not all columns have a value associated with it (e.g. `DataGridTemplateColumn`). You can get hold of the cell content using `info.Column.GetCellContent(info.Item)` though.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use CurrentCellChanged Event in DataGrid xaml.

```
 CurrentCellChanged="DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged"
```

code...

```
private void DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            var cell = grid.CurrentCell.Item;
        }
```

Comment: I'm using MVVM approach.