# How to Retrieve Values from DataGridTextColumn based on KeyBinding in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have a DataGrid to list the MobileInfo collection. The DataGrid is configured with `SelectionUnit="FullRow"`. If I click the any row then it selects the entire row with additionally it points the cell with border where the mouse hit.

The border selection moves while on keyboard navigation for example : `Left`, `Right`, `Up` and `Down`. Based on the cell selection I wish to retrieve the values from DataGridTextColumn

> Note: This Question is Purely talking about How to Retrieve Values
>   based on Passed Input (Process the Parameter and Retrieve the Values).
>   But "[How to Pass Cell Information from DataGrid in WPF KeyBinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738460/how-to-pass-cell-information-from-datagrid-in-wpf-keybinding)"
>   this question talks about how to Pass the Information from UI.
>   Here I need to Retrieve the Value **Android** from the Paramater.

Refer the image it has the output screen

[image: Retrieve Values from DataGridTextColumn]

In the above screen shot the Android is selected, based on keyboard navigation, the cell selection changes.

My XAML source code:

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MobileList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CopyToClipBoardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Column 1-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileName}" Header="Name" />
        <!--Column 2-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileOS}" Header="OS" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Note**: Don't change the SelectionUnit in the DataGrid and provide the answer using MVVM approach

Kindly provide your solution, how to pass the cell information based on keyboard navigation

The C# source code associated with the XAML DataGrid

```
public class GridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MobileInfo> MobileList { get; set; }

    public GridViewModel()
    {
        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileInfo>();
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo  { MobileName = "iPhone", MobileOS = "iOS" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo { MobileName = "Xperia", MobileOS = "Android" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileInfo { MobileName = "Lumina", MobileOS = "Windows" });
    }
}

public class MobileInfo
{
    public string MobileName { get; set; }
    public string MobileOS { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the selected-item of your `DataGrid` with:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MobileList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMobile, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

And in your ViewModel you have:

```
private MobileInfo selectedMobileInfo;
public MobileInfo SelectedMobileInfo
{
    get{ return selectedMobileInfo; }
    set
    { 
        selectedMobileInfo = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

---

If you want all selecteditems you can either pass them as Command-Parameter to your ViewModel like:

```
<KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CopyToClipBoardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mobileListDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

At your `DataGrid` you have to set `x:Name="mobileListDataGrid"` for this approach to work.

Otherwise you can bind the selected-items with an attachedproperty. This way I'll explain if you want.

Comment: It will select only one row. But my requirement is to drag the gird as like HTML Table, it should select the content as like HTML Table.